# Is encrypted but online USB PenDrive safe from ransomware attack?

Tags: windows, security, truecrypt, ransomware

Using TrueCrypt I have encrypted the entire backup pen drive but it's always connected to my Windows 7 PC.
As a result when normally dismounted it does not have a recognized file system. Only a drive letter in Explorer.

Is this kind of pen drive  set up safe from Ransomware attack?

In case ransomware hits my PC will it just exclude the pen drive from attempting to do anything?

Comment: Depends on how the ransomware was written and what the target files or drives are selected for encryption, this question is too broad.

Comment: The use of any FDS or EFS solution does not prevent another piece of software from encrypting your files.  So, the use of Truecrypt, does not prevent Ransomware

Comment: I am referring to a specific case where the entire pen drive volume e.g. \Device\Drive3\Partition1 is encrypted and it is not created as a  truecrypt  File Container that itself is susceptible to be getting re-encrypted by ransomware. When normally dismounted the drive appears to have a drive letter but it does not have a recognized file system to access anything on that drive.

Comment: @Rajeev - Any mounted volume can be encrypted by ransomware.

Answer (score 3):

"Ransomware attack" isn't a some one-size-fits-all program. They are always quite complex and rather different.

If it tries to encrypt individual files but it can't access them, then the attack will fail on that drive.

However, if it encrypts your entire disks as binary blobs, it doesn't matter how you encrypt it - it will just be re-encrypted again but a key you don't have.

Comment: Agreed. It can be volume-based and encrypt whole drives, in which case the data is affected, or it can be file specific, in which case the data in this example is safe.

Comment: Can a normally dismounted but connected pen drive fully encrypted using truecrypt be affected? It will not have a recognized file system on Windows when dismounted. By Dismount I mean connected to USB but in Encrypted status.

Comment: @rajeev it's possible to do.